# Moving multiple objects at once in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to move multiple balls at once in three.js. I made a function that creates a ball and created three balls using it. Afterwards I created a function that moves balls and it works for one ball but whenever I try to move them all at once it doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is the code:

ball function:

```
function Ball(valuex, valuey, valuez, ballname, color)
{
   var balMaterial, balGeometry, balMesh;
   balMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: color});
   balGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.3,50,50);
   balMesh = new THREE.Mesh(balGeometry, balMaterial);
   balMesh.position.set(valuex,valuey,valuez);
   balMesh.name = ballname;
   balMesh.ballDirection = new THREE.Vector3();
   balMesh.ballDirection.x = -5;
   balMesh.ballDirection.z = 1;
   balMesh.ballDirection.normalize();
   balMesh.moveSpeed = 25;
   scene.add(balMesh);
}
```

move balls:

```
function moveBalls (ball) {
var tempbal = scene.getObjectByName(ball);
var ballDirection = tempbal.ballDirection;
tempbal.position.add(speed.copy(ballDirection).multiplyScalar(clock.getDelta() * tempbal.moveSpeed));



    if (tempbal.position.x < -4.7) {
        ballDirection.x = Math.abs(ballDirection.x);
    }
    if (tempbal.position.x > 4.7) {
        ballDirection.x = -Math.abs(ballDirection.x);
    }
    if (tempbal.position.z > 12.2) {
        ballDirection.z = -Math.abs(ballDirection.z);
    }
    if (tempbal.position.z < -12.2) {
        ballDirection.z = Math.abs(ballDirection.z);
    }
    if (tempbal.moveSpeed > 0)
    {
        tempbal.moveSpeed = tempbal.moveSpeed - 0.002;
    }
}
```

Create balls:

```
Ball(0,4.5,0, "ball1", 0xffffff);
Ball(2,4.5,0, "ball2", 0xffffff);
Ball(0,4.5,6, "ball3", 0xff0000);
```

Animate Scene:

```
function animateScene()
{
    moveBalls("ball1");
    moveBalls("ball2");
    moveBalls("ball3");
    requestAnimationFrame(animateScene);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

PS: I am new here and this is my first post so if I did anything wrong in this post please tell me so I can learn from it.

Comment: I assume that 'speed' is defined somewhere else globally. What is the console output?

Comment: speed = Three.Vector3 and it's output is x = -0.022476105395295355, y = 0.0, z = -0.0044952210790590716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `clock.getDelta()` returns the seconds passed since the last call to `clock.getDelta()` which means only your first ball may move. Indeed, the first ball calls `getDelta()` (which returns something greater than 0). In the **same frame** (meaning approximately at the same time), you call `clock.getDelta()` for the 2nd ball, which returns 0. The same happens to the 3rd ball.

Try to do the following :

```
function moveBalls (ball, deltaTime) {
   var tempbal = scene.getObjectByName(ball);
    var ballDirection = tempbal.ballDirection;
    tempbal.position.add(speed.copy(ballDirection).multiplyScalar(deltaTime 
* tempbal.moveSpeed));

    if (tempbal.position.x < -4.7) {
        ballDirection.x = Math.abs(ballDirection.x);
    }
    if (tempbal.position.x > 4.7) {
        ballDirection.x = -Math.abs(ballDirection.x);
    }
    if (tempbal.position.z > 12.2) {
        ballDirection.z = -Math.abs(ballDirection.z);
    }
    if (tempbal.position.z < -12.2) {
        ballDirection.z = Math.abs(ballDirection.z);
    }
    if (tempbal.moveSpeed > 0)
    {
        tempbal.moveSpeed = tempbal.moveSpeed - 0.002;
    }
}

// ...

function animateScene()
{
    var deltaTime = clock.getDelta() ;
    moveBalls("ball1", deltaTime);
    moveBalls("ball2", deltaTime);
    moveBalls("ball3", deltaTime);
    requestAnimationFrame(animateScene);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```